# Stop setInterval timer when user clicks on another DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is some example code I am working with.  I need it so when the user clicks on an `<li id="fade-button">` the interval stops.

```js
var toggleSlide = function() {
  $("#slider li.uk-active")
    .removeClass()
    .next()
    .add("#slider li:first")
    .last()
    .addClass("uk-active");
}
setInterval(toggleSlide, 1000);
```

Comment: Keep the return value of `setInterval` and pass it to `clearInterval` when you want to stop the timer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`setInterval` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) returns the id of the interval. You can store this value and use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) to clear that specific interval when the element `#fade-button` is clicked:

[**Basic Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/awjwtufr/)

```
var intervalId = setInterval(toggleSlide, 1000);

$('#fade-button').on('click', function () {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```